# Code not printing last element of array when using using CTRL+Z to end the STDIN input

Tags: perl

I seem to have run into a peculiar problem. Here is the code

```
#read a list of strings and print in 20-character column

print "Enter your strings:\n";
chomp(@list = <STDIN>);

foreach $_ (@list){
    printf "\n%20s", $_;
}
```

The code doesn't print the last element of the array if I don't press enter before invoking end of file CTRL+Z on windows.

EDIT: Here's a sample output

```
Enter your strings:
a
v
b
                   a
                   v
```

here I pressed Ctrl-Z after entering b and before pressing enter, and it didn't print b. If I had pressed enter then Ctrl-Z, it would have printed b.

Comment: Are you using `Ctrl-Z` at the end of a line or at the beginning of a new line?

Comment: Here's a sample output

Enter your strings:
a
v
b
                   a
                   v

here I pressed Ctrl-Z after entering b, and it didn't print b

Comment: Is that your whole program? Maybe it's an output buffering issue -- what if you print another `"\n"` at the end of the loop?

Comment: @mob - yes that is the whole program.

Not sure what are you suggesting to do with the \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STDOUT is line-buffered when going to a terminal; data doesn't actually get shown until you add a newline.  Try:

```
print "Enter your strings:\n";
chomp(@list = <STDIN>);
print "\n";
foreach $_ (@list){
    printf "%20s\n", $_;
}
```

or adding `$| = 1;` before the loop.

Comment: It works. An additional question, I wrote another code using this particular code, it is having the same problem. 

`print "Enter the desired column width : ";
chomp($col = <STDIN>);


print "Enter your strings:\n";
chomp(@list = <STDIN>);

print "\n";
foreach $_ (@list){
 printf "\n%${col}s", $_;
}`